# XML serialization where request element is wrapped up with multiple parent elements

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I have a merchant account balance request class as follows:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "accountbalance", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class MerchantAccountBalanceRequest
{
    [XmlElementAttribute("agent")]
    public string Agent { get; set; }
    [XmlElementAttribute("agentPin")]
    public string AgentPin { get; set; }
}
```

Which will result in the following XML:

```
<accountbalance>
    <agent>aaaaaa</agent>
    <agentPin>mmmmmm</agentPin>
</accountbalance>
```

Could I somehow put an attribute on my class so that for the `MerchantAccountBalanceRequest` object I will get the following XML:

```
<Envelope>
<Body>
<accountbalance>
    <agent>aaaaaa</agent>
    <agentPin>mmmmmm</agentPin>
</accountbalance>
</Body>
</Envelope>
```

That is, just wrap it up with `Envelope` and `Body` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst you can't achieve this with an attribute on your request class, you can wrap your request up in other classes representing the `Envelope` and `Body` elements:

```
public class MerchantAccountBalanceRequest
{
    [XmlElement("agent")]
    public string Agent { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("agentPin")]
    public string AgentPin { get; set; }
}

public class RequestBody
{
    [XmlElement("accountbalance")]
    public MerchantAccountBalanceRequest BalanceRequest { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope")]
public class RequestEnvelope
{
    [XmlElement("Body")]
    public RequestBody Body { get; set; }
}
```

When serializing and deserializing, construct your `XmlSerializer` object from `RequestEnvelope` instead of `MerchantAccountBalanceRequest`. You will have to set the `RequestEnvelope.Body` and `RequestBody.BalanceRequest` properties when constructing them (you could probably initialize the `Body` property in `RequestEnvelope` to a new `RequestBody` instance in the constructor, for convenience).

This looks like a single request type in some protocol, so if you have multiple request types, you could create a base-class for the requests (e.g. `RequestBase`), and adjust the `RequestBody` so that it accepts a choice of the possible request elements like in the following example:

```
public abstract class RequestBase
{
}

public class SomeOtherRequest : RequestBase
{
    [XmlElementAttribute("example")]
    public string Example { get; set; }
}

public class MerchantAccountBalanceRequest : RequestBase
{
    [XmlElement("agent")]
    public string Agent { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("agentPin")]
    public string AgentPin { get; set; }
}

public class RequestBody
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "accountbalance", Type = typeof(MerchantAccountBalanceRequest))]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "somethingelse", Type = typeof(SomeOtherRequest))]
    public RequestBase Request { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I were thinking of inheritance but forgot about abstract class. Thanks a lot David

Comment: No problem :-) But how do you know my name :-o